# Including the last value in a range loop Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, range

I am having issues trying to get my code to print the last value of the range when I am running a loop. Here is the problem I was given with my code at the end:

```
start_character = "A"
end_character = "Z"

#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.

#Print all the letters from start_character to end_character,
#each on their own line. Include start_character and
#end_character themselves.
#
#Remember, you can convert a letter to its underlying ASCII
#number using the ord() function. ord("A") would give 65.
#ord("Z") would give 90. You can use these values to write
#your loop.
#
#You can also convert an integer into its corresponding ASCII
#character using the chr() function. chr(65) would give "A".
#chr(90) would give "Z". So, for this problem, you'll need
#to convert back and forth between ordinal values and
#characters based on whether you're trying to loop over
#numbers or print letters.
#
#You may assume that both start_character and end_character
#are uppercase letters (although you might find it fun to
#play around and see what happens if you put other characters
#in instead!).


#Add your code here! With the original values for
#start_character and end_character, this will print the
#letters from A to Z, each on their own line.

for char in range(ord(start_character), ord(end_character)):
    for h in chr(char):
        print(h)
```

Here is the output I receive:

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y

I know I am missing something simple, and adding +1 to end_character didn't work due to it not being a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to make sure you are adding 1 to the ordinal, not the char. Additionally you don't need the inner `for` loop, all you need to do is cast the current index back to a character with `chr()`:

```py
for char in range(ord(start_character), ord(end_character)+1):
    print(chr(char))
```

Comment: you don't need `chr(char)` just  `print(chr(char))`, because it's always a one-string, don't need to iterate on

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix - I wanted to get the answer in quickly to get out of SO purgatory.

Answer (score 0):

In the range loop you can add the +1 to the end_character like so:

```py
for char in range(ord(start_character), ord(end_character) + 1):
```

ord in python turns the character into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

use ord(end_character)+1 in for loop

ord(character): this function returns integer value (ASCII) add 1 to it.